# How to express this type in Scala? Existential with type class (ie, implicit) restriction?

Tags: scala, existential-type, implicits

I'm using the Play framework's JSON library, which uses a type class to implement the [`Json.toJson` function](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.4/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Json$).  (I may decide to use another technique with less static typing, like reflection; but for now I want to use this library because it's helping me learn the Scala type system.)

I have a bunch of simple case classes that need to be passed to `toJson`, so I have to implement an implicit `Writes[T]` object for each of them. A first cut might look like this, for each of the classes.

```
// An example class
case class Foo(title: String, lines: List[String])

// Make 'Foo' a member of the 'Writes' typeclass
implicit object FooWrites extends Writes[Foo] {
  def writes(f: Foo) : JsValue = {
    val fields = Seq("title" -> toJson(f.title), 
                     "lines" -> toJson(f.lines))                        
    JsObject(fields)
  }
}
```

Each class will have a similar implicit value, so I could abstract the common part, as below. But this doesn't compile, because I'm not sure how to declare the type.

```
def makeSimpleWrites[C](fields: (String, C => T??)*) : Writes[C] = {
  new Writes[C] {
    def writes(c: C) : JsValue = {
      val jsFields = fields map { case (name, get) => (name, toJson(get(c)))}
      JsObject(jsFields)
    }
  }
}

implicit val fooWrites : Writes[Foo] = 
    makeSimpleWrites[Foo]("title" -> {_.title}, "lines" -> {_.lines})                                 
implicit val otherWrites ...
```

The issue is the type `T` that I want to pass to `makeSimpleWrites`.  It can't be a normal type parameter because that T is different for each item in `fields`.  Is this an existential type?  I have yet to use one of these.  Flailing at syntax...

```
def makeSimpleWrites[C](fields: (String, C=>T forSome { type T; implicit Writes[T] })*)
```

Is this possible in Scala? If so, what is the syntax?

Comment: Given that the OP explictly mentions type classes , I think he knows what this is, at least superficially, right? Or maybe you can point to a specific detail of type classes that might help him in this instance?

Comment: Right, I think I understand the type class pattern.

Comment: Indeed I'am sorry, I have read you question way too fast... The only constrain on the type T is it must have an implicit of type Writes[T] ? You could use `def makeSimpleWrites[C, T : Writes](fields: (String, C=>T)*)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because each field has a different type, you would need one type parameter per field. This is because to write these fields, you need to provide (implicitly) the `Writes` instances for the corresponding types (to method `toJson`), and those are resolved statically.

One solution to work around this is to split the process in two parts: one method that you call for each field to extract the field accessor and pack it with the corresponding `WriteS` instance (this can even be maed an implicit conversion from the paairs that you are already passing), and one method that takes the whole and creates the final `WriteS` instance. Something like this (illustrative, untested):

```
class WriteSFieldAccessor[C,T] private ( val title: String, val accessor: C => Any )( implicit val writes: Writes[T] )

implicit def toWriteSFieldAccessor[C,T:Writes]( titleAndAccessor: (String, C => T) ): WriteSFieldAccessor = {
  new WriteSFieldAccessor[C,T]( titleAndAccessor._1, titleAndAccessor._2 )
}
def makeSimpleWrites[C](fields: WriteSFieldAccessor[C,_]*) : Writes[C] = {
  new Writes[C] {
    def writes(c: C) : JsValue = {
      val jsFields = fields map { f: WriteSFieldAccessor => 
        val jsField = toJson[Any](f.accessor(c))(f.writes.asInstanceOf[Writes[Any]])
        (f.title, jsField)
      }
      JsObject(jsFields)
    }
  }
}

// Each pair below is implicitly converted to a WriteSFieldAccessor  instance, capturing the required information and passing it to makeSimpleWrites
implicit val fooWrites : Writes[Foo] = makeSimpleWrites[Foo]("title" -> {_.title}, "lines" -> {_.lines})
```

The interesting part is `toJson[Any](f.accessor(c))(f.writes..asInstanceOf[Writes[Any]])`. You just pass `Any` as a the static type **but** explicitly pass the (normally implicit) `Writes` instance.

Comment: Very nice answer! I forget that here we would need one type parameter per field...

Comment: Aha, I think I see why I need to package up the implicit Writes like you did.  Though now I'm having some trouble getting this to compile.  I added (f.writes.asInstanceOf[Any]), but now it doesn't like the anonymous functions on the last line.  `missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.title)`.  I'll report more later.

Comment: This would rather be `f.writes.asInstanceOf[Writes[Any]]`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: It appears I have to write `"title" -> {s:Section => s.title}` instead of `"title" -> {_.title}` to get it to compile.  Not a big deal, but do you have any more tricks to fix that?

Comment: Have a look at my other answer.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to address the restriction that with my first solution one has to write `"title" -> {s:Section => s.title}` instead of `"title" -> {_.title}`, I tinkered a bit with it, only to run in scala's inference limitation all the time.
So I decided to try to tackle it from another angle and came with a completly different solution.
This is basically a quasi-DSL:

```
class ExpandableWrites[C]( val fields: Vector[(String, C => Any, Writes[_])] ) extends Writes[C] {
  def and[T:Writes](fieldAccessor: C => T)(fieldName: String): ExpandableWrites[C] = {
    new ExpandableWrites( fields :+ (fieldName, fieldAccessor, implicitly[Writes[T]]) )
  }
  def writes(c: C) : JsValue = {
    val jsFields = fields map { case (name, get, writes) => (name, toJson[Any](get(c))(writes.asInstanceOf[Writes[Any]]) )}
    JsObject(jsFields)
  }
}

class UnaryExpandableWritesFactory[C] {
  def using[T:Writes](fieldAccessor: C => T)(fieldName: String): ExpandableWrites[C] = {
    new ExpandableWrites[C]( Vector( (fieldName, fieldAccessor, implicitly[Writes[T]] ) ) )
  }
}

def makeSimpleWritesFor[C] = new UnaryExpandableWritesFactory[C]

implicit val fooWrites : Writes[Foo] = 
  makeSimpleWritesFor[Foo].using(_.title)("title") .and (_.lines)("lines") .and (_.date)("date")
```

The idea is that you create your `Writes` instance step by step, and enrich it with new fields one by one.
The only annoyance is that you do need the `.and` separator, including the dot. Without the dot (that is, using infix notation), the compiler seems to be confused again and complains  if we just do `(_.title)` instead of `(s:Section => s.title)`.

Answer (score 1):

As of at least Jan 25 2015, play-json already has a built-in way of doing what you want:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

sealed case class Foo(title: String, lines: List[String])  // the `sealed` bit is not relevant but I always seal my ADTs

implicit val fooWrites = (
  (__ \ "title").write[String] ~
  (__ \ "lines").write[List[String]]
)(unlift(Foo.unapply))
```

in fact, this also works with `Reads[T]`

```
implicit val fooReads = (
  (__ \ "title").read[String] ~
  (-- \ "lines").read[List[String]]
)(Foo.apply _)
```

and `Format[T]`:

```
implicit val fooFormat = (
  (__ \ "title").format[String] ~
  (-- \ "lines").format[List[String]]
)(Foo.apply _, unlift(Foo.unapply))
```

you can also apply transforms, e.g.:

```
implicit val fooReads = (
  (__ \ "title").read[String].map(_.toLowerCase) ~
  (-- \ "lines").read[List[String]].map(_.filter(_.nonEmpty))
)(Foo.apply _)
```

or even 2-way transforms:

```
implicit val fooFormat = (
  (__ \ "title").format[String].inmap(_.toLowerCase, _.toUpperCase) ~
  (-- \ "lines").format[List[String]]
)(Foo.apply _, unlift(Foo.unapply))
```