# scala - get type of list element

Tags: scala, collections, macros, type-conversion, type-erasure

Assume I have

```
class A(val x:Int)
class B(val x:Int)
class C(val x:Int)
```

and

```
implicit def aPrinter = new PrettyPrinter[A] {def printed(a:A) = s"A(${a.x})"}
implicit def bPrinter = new PrettyPrinter[B] {def printed(b:B) = s"B(${b.x})"}
implicit def cPrinter = new PrettyPrinter[C] {def printed(c:C) = s"C(${c.x})"}
```

(side note: could also use some help in figuring out how to avoid this boiler plate [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320547/scala-implicit-macros-materialisation))

where

```
trait PrettyPrinter[T]{
  def printed(x:T) : String
}

object PrettyPrinter{
  def pretty[T](x:T)(implicit pretty:PrettyPrinter[T]) = pretty printed x

  implicit def prettyList[T:ClassTag](implicit p :PrettyPrinter[T]) = new PrettyPrinter[List[T]] {
    def printed(x:List[T]) = x.map(p.printed).mkString("List(",", ",")")
  }
}
```

If I want to print collections of a type I have specified, e.g.

```
val as = new A(1) :: new A(7) :: new A(3) :: Nil
println(pretty(as))
```

Things work fine.

However, I have no luck with

```
val list = new A(1) :: new B(2) :: new C(9) :: new A(7) :: new A(3) :: Nil
```

because they are simply considered instances of `Object` and I don't have a `PrettyPrinter[Object]`.

Any way to overcome this limitation?

i.e. what I want is something like this (doesn't compile because tries to find `PrettyPrinter[T]`):

```
implicit def prettyList[T:ClassTag] = new PrettyPrinter[List[T]] {
  def printed(x:List[T]) = x.map(pretty).mkString("List(",", ",")")
}
```

which would try to find an implicit `PrettyPrinter` for each element's *actual* type (`PrettyPrinter[A]` for the first element, `PrettyPrinter[B]` for the second, ...).

Comment: Maybe make a generic printer for two elements concated in an `HList`, and a specific one for `HNil`; something along the lines of `implicit def hlistPrinter[A : PrettyPrinter, B : PrettyPrinter] = new PrettyPrinter[A :: B] { def printed(list: A :: B) = implicitly[PrettyPrinter[A]].printed(list._0) + " :: " + implicitly[PrettyPrinter[B]].printed(list._1) }; implicit def hnilPrinter = new PrettyPrinter[HNil] { def printed(nil: HNil) = "HNil" }`. This type of solution should cover all list sizes because the second (or first) element can just be another `HList`.

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865947/how-to-express-this-type-in-scala-existential-with-type-class-ie-implicit-re.

Comment: @Doc I'm not familiar with ``HList``, but unless I am mistaken, this again assumes I know the classes that will be in the list and completely disregards the possibility the client may insert his own classes and provide ``PrettyPrinter`` instances for them.

Comment: As far as I know, if you don't know the type of the objects you can't use implicit resolution because that's a compile time thing. Instead you could make the objects inherit from a `PrettyPrintable` trait which declares its own `print` method that's overridden by subclasses; then the objects can be downcasted and they'll still have their specific methods. You can wrap types without the trait such as `String` or even `List[PrettyPrintable]` in implicit classes with the trait.

Comment: @User1291, the `HList` approach doesn't require knowing the classes which will be in the list. You implement a recursive method which declares the `PrettyPrinter` instance for the next list element as an implicit parameter. This way the compiler is able to resolve the required `PrettyPrinter` instances for all list elements. The client can provide additional classes with `PrettyPrinter` instances.